# Combustion chamber question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[What Constitutes A Combustion Chamber?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36318/what-constitutes-a-combustion-chamber)

We don't 'do' fuel questions, but what about this one?
Should it be closed or is it 'innocent' enough?
I lean towards accepting it.

Related meta: [Why can't I ask my question about amateur space projects and development?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/why-cant-i-ask-my-question-about-amateur-space-projects-and-development)

Comment: No offense, but this isn't really about fuel or that dangerous.

Comment: @Putvi: I had the same concern as Jan when reading the question.  If you edit out the "I am thinking of building" part and make it more of a theoretical design question, then it should be fine.

Comment: I mean I'll edit it if you guys want, but people do build these things.

Comment: @Putvi: I saw your edit, but it didn't quite address the amateur-building-a-rocket issue.  I edited the question to make it more suitable.  You are welcome to roll the change back, but you might risk other users flagging the question as dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

This question is about how a highly space-related technology works. We answer such questions all the time.

We close questions about how to home-make stuff, most importantly fuel. The question does not ask how you would make a combustion chamber at home. It asks how one works *in principle*.

I do not see any reason why that question should be closed.