# Should we have a comment left behind when closing questions about building your own rocket (propellant)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, comments

Recently, I [reviewed this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/30259) and voted to close for the danger of constructing a homemade rocket engine. I left this comment:

> Questions about dangerous amateur experiments, such as **constructing your own engine or propellants** are off-topic. Rockets and their propellants are **INHERENTLY DANGEROUS** and can pose hazards to not just yourself, but others around you (friends, family, neighbors, etc). **It may also be illegal.** Please see [this meta post for more information](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1031).

This is a lot to type and format from the original close reason. Can we have an option (or automatically) to leave a comment regarding this problem, as the new user may not know what is wrong, it seems like a nicely written question without any errors, except for the building-rocket part.

**Attached is the bare copy-paste comment for convenience:**

Questions about dangerous amateur experiments, such as **constructing your own engine or propellants** are off-topic. Rockets and their propellants are **INHERENTLY DANGEROUS** and can pose hazards to not just yourself, but others around you (friends, family, neighbors, etc). **It may also be illegal.** Please see [this meta post for more information]([https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1031\](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1031%5C)).

Comment: We already have a custom close reason for this. Why do you think we also need a comment?

Comment: If I understand correctly, *the question author* definitely sees a big banner with that close reason and is asked to agree or disagree with it and to make edits to address the close reason. We don't see that banner but they do. However I don't know why voting to close as duplicate does auto-generate the comment "Does this answer your question?" but voting to close as dangerous doesn't.

Comment: @uhoh You've got yourself a feature request there!

Comment: @fasterthanlight no I really don't, a lot of thought and discussion has gone into how SE works, more than I can wrap my head around. I'm still waiting for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324104/303080) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331664/303080).